# using .map on an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, array.prototype.map

I'm an R programmer and think of arrays in javascript kind of like lists in R. In R when I want to access elements of a list I would use `lapply()` and `do.call` to apply a function to the inner elements and then place the result into a new data structure. I read about the `map` function in javascript but I can't seems to crack it in my case:

```
data = {"type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "CRS" } },
    "features": [
        { "type": "Feature",
          "id": 6,
          "properties": {"species": "giraffe",
                 "result": 0,
                 "popup_text": "Some text" },
          "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1, 5] } },
        { "type": "Feature",
          "id": 7,
          "properties": { "species": "pig",
                  "result": 0,
                  "popup_text": "Some text" },
          "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2,3 ] } },
        { "type": "Feature",
          "id": 8,
          "properties": { "species": "goat",
                  "result": 0,
                  "popup_text": "Some Text" },
          "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1,6 ] } },
        { "type": "Feature",
          "id": 16,
          "properties": { "species": "giraffe",
                  "result": 0,
                  "popup_text": "Some Text" },
          "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 3,4 ] } },
        { "type": "Feature",
          "id": 18,
          "properties": { "species": "pig",
               "result": 0,
               "popup_text": "Some Text" },
          "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2,7 ] } }
    ]
       }
```

So, `data.features` is an array of 5 elements, each of these elements contains 4 arrays: `type`, `id`,  `properties`,  `geometry`. I would like to generate a new array that is just the `properties.result` value. It would have a structure like this:

```
newdata = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

So far I tried the following but it doesn't result in what I want:

```
var result = data.features.map(function(i) {
    return{
    result: i.properties.result
    };
});
console.log(result)
```

Any ideas how I can do this? In the end my purpose is to determine if `any` of the `result == 1`

Comment: If you want to return a number - return a number: `return i.properties.result;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the output you wanted you just needed

```
var result = data.features.map(function(i) {
    return i.properties.result;    
});
```

That will result in an array of `[0,0,0,0,0]`.

To determine if any of them are 1 you could use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
var areAny1 = result.some(function(x) { return x == 1; });
```

Live example below

```js
var data = {"type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "CRS" } },
    "features": [
        { "type": "Feature",
          "id": 6,
          "properties": {"species": "giraffe",
                 "result": 0,
                 "popup_text": "Some text" },
          "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1, 5] } },
        { "type": "Feature",
          "id": 7,
          "properties": { "species": "pig",
                  "result": 0,
                  "popup_text": "Some text" },
          "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2,3 ] } },
        { "type": "Feature",
          "id": 8,
          "properties": { "species": "goat",
                  "result": 0,
                  "popup_text": "Some Text" },
          "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1,6 ] } },
        { "type": "Feature",
          "id": 16,
          "properties": { "species": "giraffe",
                  "result": 0,
                  "popup_text": "Some Text" },
          "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 3,4 ] } },
        { "type": "Feature",
          "id": 18,
          "properties": { "species": "pig",
               "result": 0,
               "popup_text": "Some Text" },
          "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2,7 ] } }
    ]
       };

var result = data.features.map(function(x){
      return x.properties.result;
});
console.log(result);

var areAny1 = result.some(function(x) { return x === 1 });
console.log(areAny1);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to generate a new array that is just the
>   properties.result value.

You were almost on the right path

```
var result = data.features.map(function(i) {
    return i.properties.result;
});
console.log(result)
```

> In the end my purpose is to determine if any of the result == 1

you can use `filter`

```
var hasAny1 = data.features.filter(function(i) {
    return i.properties.result == 1;
}).length > 0;
console.log(hasAny1);
```

Or use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
var hasAny1 = data.features.some(function(i) {
    return i.properties.result == 1;
});
console.log(hasAny1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just return the value that you want to be an element of the new array:

```
data.features.map(function (x) { 
    return x.properties.result; 
});
```